# template literal dosn't work except backslash

Tags: javascript

```js
let str = 'asdwazsgdsadf' + 'qetgsadfdf';
let str2 = `asdqwedd  qrqwee
fqfqw
qrwrq`;
      
let v1 = 100;
let v2 = 200;
let v3 = v1 * v2;
let str3 = `\${v1} * \${v2} = \${v3}`;
let t1 = 'hong'

console.log('v1 : ', `${v1}`); // out = v1 : 
console.log('t1 : ', `${t1}`); // out = t1 : 
console.log('str2 : ', str2);
console.log('str3 : ', str3); // out = str3 :  100 * 200 = 20000
```

this is my template literal test code.
other people can use `${v1}` but my code is look like null.

what's matter of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

```
`${v1} * ${v2} = ${v3}`
```

you should get the console log:

"100 * 200 = 20000"

but, whenever u add that backslash it takes away the speciality of the immediate special character followed by it , in your case, ($)

Comment: i find the answer, jsp and javascript have same ${} and other function i solve code 
\`${ '${v1} * ${v2} = ${v3}'}\`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more I'd say that you should check your environment to be sure that it can run template literals.

Check this list: [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)

Comment: i find the answer, jsp and javascript have same ${} and other function i solve code \`${ '${v1} * ${v2} = ${v3}'}\`